# Parent height smaller than child, why?

Tags: html, css, jquery-backstretch

I'm trying to stretch an image vertically in a parent container of my site (not the full body), it is the div with the id "imagen-fondo"

I have tried either backstretch plugin and also just css background-image with background-size to do it.

But the problem in both cases is that the calculated height of the parent container is smaller that the immediate child height, so, the background image looks smaller than the content itself.

How can I make it to be the same height as his immediate child or at least bigger?

You can see the live demo here:

```
http://50.21.181.12:3001/plantillas/mba
```

[image: Screenshot shows the height of the parent div]

[image: Screenshot shows the height of the child div]

UPDATE:

I think the problem is that div#imagen-fondo is getting the height of the window and not of his content, that is the reason that when the screen is big, the problem doesn't happen, but when the height of the window is smaller than the content it happens, you can check it with this two screenshots, just as you start scrolling vertical the background image ends:

[image: step 1, scroll to the top]
[image: step2, scrolling a little shows that the background ends]

Something with overflows?

UPDATE 2:

For now I introduced some javascript to make it work,

Getting the footer offset position and stretching the height of the ".backstretch" div to that height.

But, if you resize the window to make the vertical scroll bar appear and inspect the page, you can still see that the parent container "#imagen-fondo" (from where backstretch should automatically get his height) is still getting the height of the visible viewport and not from the content itself.

If anyone finds a better way to do it CSS only will use that approach instead of this dirty one.

Comment: I have tested it in IE8, IE9, FF and Chrome. In all browsers it looks fine to me

Comment: Hi, it appears that it depends on the viewport, a big screen doesn't produce this result (my Ubuntu box with default size) but resizing the window to for example 1203 x 529 makes the issue appear (#imagen-fondo height gets smaller than #wrap height)

Comment: OK, I have now sen it happen. What is even more funny is, that when you resize the height of the viewport back and forth It gets step by step better. (At least in FF)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For now I introduced some javascript to make it work,

Reading the footer position and stretching the height of the ".backstretch" div to that height.

But, if you resize the window to make the vertical scroll bar appear and inspect the page, you can still see that the parent container "#imagen-fondo" (from where backstretch should automatically get his height) is still getting the height of the visible viewport and not from the content itself.

If anyone finds a better way to do it CSS only will use that approach instead of this dirty one.

Answer (score 0):

Clear floats in parent div using clear: both;
Or use clearfix on parent div.

Comment: Hi, I have added clearfixes to check if that resolves the problem, you can check them now in the site, but it is still happening the same :(